# how to remove authors and tags from sitemap in ghost blog.?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, blogs, ghost-blog

A quick question about sitemap. Is it possible to regenerate the sitemap? I want to remove tag and author pages from sitemap for SEO purpose. There's a another way to disabled tags and author to remove from routes.yml which means 404 pages so that would be bad impact on SEO.

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove the tags and authors pages from the sitemap, you have edit the file `/current/core/frontend/services/sitemap/manager.js` of your Ghost installation.

In that file, you will have to modify the `createIndexGenerator()` method, removing the lines related to tags and authors. After modifying it, the method will look like the following:

```
createIndexGenerator() {
  return new IndexMapGenerator({
    types: {
      pages: this.pages,
      posts: this.posts
    }
  });
}
```

And you are done!

Please, take into account that file modified belongs to the Ghost core, so it will be overwritten when updating Ghost.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of ghost, the file has been named SiteMapManager.js. To open the file, first open the folder where your ghost installation is located. For example, if you installed ghost in /var/www/site-name then, you must add it to the rest of the path.
The full path will look like this:

```
/var/www/site-name/current/core/frontend/services/sitemap
```

So change directory :

```
cd /var/www/site-name/current/core/frontend/services/sitemap
```

and then open the file :

```
nano SiteMapManager.js
```

Scroll to the bottom and you will find the code you need to edit:

```
    createIndexGenerator() {
    return new IndexMapGenerator({
    types: {
    pages: this.pages,
    posts: this.posts,
    tags: this.tags,
    users: this.users
    }
    });
  }
```

Remove these two lines and you are done:

```
    tags: this.tags,
    users: this.users,
```

This will remove the author and tag sitemap from your sitemap index. You can apply noindex headers to both in your nginx configuration if you want them noindexed.

Answer (score -1):

Update:

Rather than removing authors and tags entirely you can generate a custom sitemap using `routes.yaml` and a custom template. The official Ghost docs shows how to create a sitemap for Google News, which can also be applied for a custom XML Sitemap: https://ghost.org/docs/tutorials/create-a-google-news-sitemap/

---

You'll need to remove them from the `routes.yaml` file. The default is:

```
taxonomies:
  tag: /tag/{slug}/
  author: /author/{slug}/
```

Removing these lines will remove the author and tag pages from the sitemap and from the site entirely.

You'll also need to update your theme to not link to these pages, to prevent 404 errors from appearing.